# Get a row, then others order by id

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I get a specific row (id=x) and then the reminders? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id=5 FIRST THAN id DESC
```

I tried to use UNION ALL, like:

```
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=5) 
 UNION ALL 
(SELECT * FROM table WHERE id!=5 ORDER BY id DESC)
```

but the result is unexpected since the second SELECT doesn't return the registers ordered by id (desc). In addition, in this way is neccessary to write much more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id = 5 DESC, id ASC
```

This will give you something like: 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, ...

Answer (score 2):

You can put more than one clause on the `order by` line:

```
select *
from t
order by (case when id = 5 then 1 else 0 end) desc, id desc
```

Also, tables and result sets in SQL are unordered.  The one exception is the use of `order by` for a result set.  I wouldn't expect the `union all` method to work.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you '5's first, then 'not 5's

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY case when id=5 then 0 else 1 end ASC
```